# In Python, how can I change the sign of one number in a list based on another number's sign?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sign

I have two values in a list, let's say it's

```
A = [1, -3]
```

If the sign of the second value is positive, I can leave the number alone. If the sign of the second value is negative, I need to change the first value to be a -1. But if the first value is a 0, nothin needs to be done at all, since -0 is the same as a positive zero.

So in the case of A, I would need to change 1 to -1. So the final result should be

```
A = [-1, -3]
```

I'm a new programmer, so basically all I think is that it involves appending a value to the end of A, and then removing the first value. I think we have to do that because as far as I know, there's no way of just changing the sign of a number.

So, I think it might be something like this:

```
A = [1, -3]
for i in A:
    if #something about the second value being a positive value
        pass
    else:
        A.append("-1")
        del A[0]
print A
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
if A[1] < 0:
    A[0] *= -1
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one liner ought to do it:

```
A = [1, -3]
A = [-A[0] if A[-1] < 0 else A[0], A[-1]]

print A
```

This would produce the expected output of:

```
[-1, -3]
```

---

*Note: `A[-1]` means the last element of the list, this is the same as `A[1]` in this case*

Comment: This is how I would have done it atleast :D But I think you misread the question.

Comment: See cforbish's answer.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I'm also doing pretty much the same thing :P

Answer (score 1):

```
A=[1,3]
if A[1]<0:A[0]*=-1
print A
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is much simpler:

```
if A[1] < 0:
    A[0] = -1
```